# No se visualiza el caracter ñ en pantalla

Tags: c

Estoy usando ASCII, pero ese es el resultado. 
ejecutado en codeblocks 17.12

```
printf("\nAhora ingrese su contrase%a: ", 164);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De tu pregunta parece deducirse que esperabas que el `%` fuera sustituido por un carácter, cuyo código sería el 164  que le pasas como parámetro (que aparentemente sería la `ñ` en la tabla de códigos que estés usando.

Esto no es así, `%` es un prefijo cuya intepretación depende del carácter que aparezca después. Para que funcione como esperabas, debes usar `%c` (pues esa es la cadena de formato para mostrar un único carácter).

En tu caso, tras el `%` había una `a`, y eso produce el extraño resultado que puedes ver. La cadena de formato `%a` es bastante poco frecuente, pues lo que hace es tomar el número de 32 bits que le especifiques (en tu caso el 164) e interpretarlo como si estuviera codificado en el formato IEEE-754 de punto flotante, para mostrarte entonces su mantisa y su exponente ambos en hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

En vez de usar `%a` debes usar `%c`

```
printf("\nAhora ingrese su contrase%ca: ", 164);
```

Al símbolo del porcentaje seguido de una letra %x se le conoce como especificador de formato, en tu caso %a es un especificador de formato introducido en C99 para imprimir números con coma flotante de forma hexadecimal.

En el siguiente link podras consultar una lista a profundidad de los especificadores de formato.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta ya está resuelta pero quería añadir una cosita. El uso de valores literales para imprimir caracteres no garantiza que la impresión del símbolo que quieres se realice correctamente en todas las plataformas. Más aún, se considera una mala práctica por lo que mi recomendación es que uses el carácter 'ñ' directamente y que guardes el archivo en una codificación adecuada.

Hecho esto, es posible darle información al compilador sobre cuál es la codificación en que está guardado el archivo e información sobre el conjunto de caracteres de ejecución. Si haces esos dos pasos correctamente podrás imprimir las ñes y acentos escribiéndolos directamente.

Para hacerlo tienes que entrar en la pestaña de 'settings' o configuraciones y luego a 'Compiler...' o 'Compilador' tal como se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habrá unas pestañas en el cuadro de dialogo resultante, elige la pestaña 'Other options' o 'otras opciones de compilador':

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En dicha pestaña, tendrás disponible un espacio en blanco en donde puedes poner opciones del compilador. Las opciones que deberías poner son:

-finput-charset=iso8859-1
-finput-charset=cp850

iso8859-1 es la codificación en que se guardan por defecto los archivos en windows y cp850 es la codificación de la consola. Con esas dos opciones activas deberías poder escribir instrucciones como:

```
printf(" Acentos: áéíóú\n Letra eñe: Ñ\n");
```

Y obtener como resultado:

```
 Acentos: áéíóú
 Letra eñe: Ñ
```

Comment: No funciona. Al menos no para mi. 
Una sugerencia seria usar setconsolecp para mudar la codificación del cmd para windows1252 por ejemplo, ambas deben ser la misma, tanto en el cmd como no programa que va ser usado. Codeblocks trabaja con windows-1252 por default no windows.